# Can I mass update stock item vendor details through Acumatica mass update GI?

Tags: acumatica

I have a GI showing the vendor cross references as well as the vendor details for stock items.

It would be supremely useful for end users to be able to enter vendor details directly into this screen.  (Sometimes they may be able to copy over from the Xrefs)

I can set up the GI to allow mass update, but the vendor detail fields are not available in the mass update fields when I select Stock Items as the Entry screen.

Is there a way to allow users to do this mass update from a GI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, mass update fields on a GI can only be selected from the primary top-level record. At least based on my personal experience, I could never select fields from any other DAC than the primary top-level record.

I highly doubt that this is the answer you expected to hear, but as an alternative, you can always create your own custom data entry screen to allow end users enter vendor details directly into this screen and even provide an option to copy over from the Xrefs...

Comment: Always useful to know what we can or can't achieve with a particular feature.